# Update file inside Docker Container with Shiny Application

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I am deploying a shiny app with docker. As part of this app is a data file which can be overwritten and updated from within the shiny application, like so.

```
observeEvent(input$upload_data,{
    file.copy(input$upload_data$datapath, "../data.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
})
```

So every time a new data file is uploaded to input$upload_data, it should overwrite the existing data.xlsx file with the new upload.

This works perfectly when running the app on my Windows machine, however when the app is running in Docker, the data file is not being overwritten. When the app is launched the data file used is the one that was originally present when the Docker image was generated.

Comment: have you defined a volume for the container? Is this volume writable? Is the dockerfile configured to overwrite the file in the volume with a default one?

It would help if you could provide the dockerfile oder docker-compose.yml

Comment: I have none of that :) The writable volume is defined in the dockerfile? Dockerfile coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker does not persist any data unless it is told to do so. For this case Volumes were introduced which will persist data of your Container. Otherwise all Data does only exist in RAM and will be discarded after container shutdown.

For more information you should read the following article:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/